# Why cant I merge trading view indicators on PineScript V1 Code and V5 code which keeps giving me errors?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Can anyone kindly tell me what im doing wrong when I try to merge two Indicators on Tradingview? One indicator code is V5 and the other is V1. Why is it not possible to merge them into one indicator? I have no idea what I'm doing as I'm new to all this. Below are the codes for both indicators that I am copy-pasting with all the logic that was written so far.

```
//@version=5

// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/

indicator(title='SUPER TREND CANDLES', overlay=true, shorttitle='STC')
src = close
len = input.int(8, minval=1, title='Length')
up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(src), 0), len)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - 100 / (1 + up / down)

//coloring method below``
src1 = close
len = input.int(8, minval=1, title='Length')
src2 = close
len2 = input.int(50, minval=1, title='DownLevel')
   rsi > len1
isdown() =>
   rsi < len2
isdown_1 = isdown()
barcolor(isup() ? color.green : isdown_1 ? color.red : an)

//study('buy/sell arrows', overlay=true)

out = ta.sma(close, 50)
data = rsi > len1 ? open[1] > close[1] ? close > open ? close >= open[1] ? close[1] >= open ? close - open > open[1] - close[1] ? high > out : na : na : na : na : na : na
data1 = rsi < len2 ? close[1] > open[1] ? open > close ? open >= close[1] ? open[1] >= close ? open - close > close[1] - open[1] ? low < out : na : na : na : na : na : an


ema1 = input(34, minval=1, maxval=300, title="EMA UpTrend")
shema = input(true, title="Show EMA Trend is Based On?")

usedEma = ema(close, ema1)

emaUpColor() => hlc3 >= usedEma
emaDownColor() => hlc3  < usedEma


col = hlc3  >= usedEma ? lime : hlc3  < usedEma ? red : white

barcolor(emaUpColor() ? lime: emaDownColor() ? red : an)
plot(shema and usedEma ? usedEma : na, title="EMA", style=line, linewidth=3, color=col
```

When I try to merge these two code to a single indicator I get the following error....

**Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 34: The arguments 'maxval', 'minval', and 'step' cannot be used with the input() function. You can use the input.int() or input.float() functions to specify a range of input data values.**

Pls help me solve this before I start breaking my computer. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you the solution. If you want to use `minval` or `maxval` arguments, you cannot use the plain `input()` function.

You should use `input.int()` or `input.float()` instead.

`ema1 = input.int(34, minval=1, maxval=300, title="EMA UpTrend")`

Comment: Thats it? I dont have to change any other values?

Comment: To fix that error, that’s it. You will get other errors once you fix it.